# Need regex_extract SQL query to return value that "starts with" and "ends with" certain character

Tags: sql, regex, string, hive

I have strings in my data set that are like this:
aaaabbbbccccddddkeyword=dragon&morestuff=123

I need to have a query that will extract **dragon**. So the query needs to "start with" keyword= and "end with" &, but trims keyword= and the & at the end. It needs to return everything between those two things. I know I need something like this:

select regexp_extract(table_name, '[^keyword] [&$]') as keywordvalue

But can't seem to put it together. I know that ^ defines the beginning of the string and $ defines the end, but the formatting of the query is eluding me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a properly formatted HTTP query string: Hive has [string function `parse_url()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions).

```
select parse_url(col, 'QUERY', 'keyword') as k_word
from mytable
```